# Create dynamic banner with Image Handler

Tags: asp.net, imagehandler

I want to create my own dynamic banner, so I started to create an Image Handler, atm I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Faeria
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FaeriaImage
/// </summary>
public class FaeriaImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.Write("~/Images/bg1.jpg");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

But when I call "http:// localhost :12361/FaeriaImage.ashx" I only get this: http://abload.de/image.php?img=1deib0.jpg.

And when I call it in my site with   I get no image.

Whats is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the handler and as far as I know you need to draw the image in the handler. This code might help you as it helped me. Try it out

```
 using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/bg1.jpg")))
 {
   using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to the following (not write but WriteFile)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.WriteFile("~/Images/bg1.jpg");
}
```